# How to order row by specific value? MySQL CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a issue. 
My sql query don't work in codeigniter, when i try to order by specific value
Here's example:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Questions');
$this->db->where('Questions.Status !=', 0);
$this->db->order_by('IdQuestion', 'DESC');
$this->db->order_by('(CASE WHEN Status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)', 'DESC'); //Here's wrong...
```

But i don't receive valid result.
Someone can help.
Second order_by statement is wrong.

CASE don't work correct.

Comment: @JayBlanchard question is not about how to sort in general, but how to sort by value which is the result of `CASE`.

Comment: Ah - gotcha @u_mulder. Not enough coffee and too much ice this morning.

Comment: Not sure of the specifics with CodeIgniter, but try adding the CASE statement as a column in the SELECT with an alias, then try ordering by the alias.

Comment: @flip I suppose this is the correct approach.

Comment: @flip thank you, i'll try. ;)

Comment: @flip not working :(

Comment: @DanPlaton Can you post the query that CodeIgniter is producing and your expected results please?

Comment: @flip I have already found the solution. Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solutions is that:
To create view which will contains all results ordered, before select this view in codeigniter model

Example:

```
select (case when (`parajurist`.`intrebari`.`Status` = 2) then 1 else 2 end) 
AS `Second`,`parajurist`.`intrebari`.`IdIntrebare` AS 
`IdIntrebare`,`parajurist`.`intrebari`.`Titlu` AS 
`Titlu`,`parajurist`.`intrebari`.`Descriere` AS 
`Descriere`,`parajurist`.`intrebari`.`NumePrenumeP` AS 
`NumePrenumeP`,`parajurist`.`intrebari`.`EmailP` AS 
`EmailP`,`parajurist`.`intrebari`.`Status` AS 
`Status`,`parajurist`.`intrebari`.`IdCategorie` AS 
`IdCategorie`,`parajurist`.`intrebari`.`DataAdresare` AS 
`DataAdresare`,`parajurist`.`intrebari`.`Comments` AS 
`Comments`,`parajurist`.`intrebari`.`CuvCheie` AS `CuvCheie` from 
(`parajurist`.`intrebari` join `parajurist`.`intrebaricategorii` 
on((`parajurist`.`intrebaricategorii`.`IdCategorie` = 
`parajurist`.`intrebari`.`IdCategorie`))) where 
(`parajurist`.`intrebari`.`Status` <> 0) order by (case when 
(`parajurist`.`intrebari`.`Status` = 2) then 1 else 2 
end),`parajurist`.`intrebari`.`IdIntrebare` desc
```

and codeigniter code:

```
$this->db->limit($start, $stop);

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->select('LEFT(intrebari_view.Titlu, 50) as Titlu');
    $this->db->select('LEFT(intrebari_view.Descriere, 150) AS Descriere');
    $this->db->join('IntrebariCategorii', 'IntrebariCategorii.IdCategorie = intrebari_view.IdCategorie');
    $this->db->where('IntrebariCategorii.NumeCategorie', $cat);
    $this->db->from('intrebari_view');
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this solution for your problem :

```
<?php 

$sub_query_from = '(SELECT Questions.*, (CASE WHEN Questions.Status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) as questions_status from Questions  WHERE Questions.Status != 0 ORDER BY IdQuestion DESC) as sub_questions';
$this->db->select('sub_questions.*');
$this->db->from($sub_query_from);
$this->db->order_by('sub_questions.questions_status', 'DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();

echo "<per>";
print_r($result);
exit;

?>
```

Hope it will helps.